# having different visibility for different store views

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to be able to have the ability to just have different store views with particular visibility and not all follow the same strcuture - i know this is possibly by clicking the top left dropdown on store view but we want to be able to do this via CSV or Magmi CSV - and this unfortunately puts it into 2 lines.

Is there a way to code a fix so that particular store views always show in catalog?

We also dont want to create new categories as this adds a further level of complexity.

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

In store views we must need to add two rows to manage the visibility of a product. That is because

1. First row means it will set all attribute value for all the store view.
2. Second row is required to set different value (ex visibility) for any specific store.

**Better if you can go for website level.**

In website level you will get more other useful option also.

- You can apply mass action & make product visible or not visible in website level. Inside:

> Admin->Catalog->Manage Products->Select products->Update
>   attributes->Website

.